# Show quantity input as readonly on cart page when min value is equal to max value in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, product-quantity

Applying this filter with min and max = 1 will make quantity input field disappear on cart page:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'custom_cart_qty_range', 10, 2 );        

function custom_cart_qty_range( $args, $product ) {
   $args['min_value'] = 1;
   $args['max_value'] = 1;
   return $args;
}
```

I completely don't understand this "feature", because customers don't see item quantity at all. I would like to make input `readonly` and apply custom CSS instead. I have this CSS ready, but what I need is to stop WooCommerce from making an exception for quantity input field when min = max.

On product page when min = max (presented filter doesn't work on product page quantity) input field is still visible, what is desired outcome for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to stop this behavior from WooCommerce, you will need to override `global/quantity-input.php` template file via your active theme.

First read [*"How to override woocommerce templates via your active theme"*](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/) that explains how to copy a template file from WooCommerce plugin to your theme's folder to make some desired changes.

**The related template file to copy is:** `global/quantity-input.php`

Once it has been copied inside your theme inside a "woocommerce" folder on "global" subfolder, open / edit `quantity-input.php` file and change the following block of code *(from line **`21`** to **`25`**)*:

```
?>
<div class="quantity hidden">
    <input type="hidden" id="<?php echo esc_attr( $input_id ); ?>" class="qty" name="<?php echo esc_attr( $input_name ); ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $min_value ); ?>" />
</div>
<?php
```

By the following:

```
?>
<div class="quantity">
    <input type="text" id="<?php echo esc_attr( $input_id ); ?>" class="qty" name="<?php echo esc_attr( $input_name ); ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $min_value ); ?>" readonly="readonly" />
</div>
<?php
```

Save, you are done.

Now when `min_value` will be equal to `max_value`, the field will be displayed **as read only** with the correct value.

---

Now if you need that only in cart page, you will have to make this change instead:

```
if ( is_cart() ) {
    ?>
    <div class="quantity">
        <input type="text" id="<?php echo esc_attr( $input_id ); ?>" class="qty" name="<?php echo esc_attr( $input_name ); ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $min_value ); ?>" readonly="readonly" />
    </div>
    <?php
} else {
    ?>
    <div class="quantity hidden">
        <input type="hidden" id="<?php echo esc_attr( $input_id ); ?>" class="qty" name="<?php echo esc_attr( $input_name ); ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $min_value ); ?>" />
    </div>
    <?php
}
```